# Zip a file in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to Zip my files with C# code but its showing that ZipFile class does't exist. Please suggest how to Zip with C# and I am using Framework 4.5

My code is written below

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;


namespace ZipSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] MainDirs = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\users\\public\reports");

            for (int i = 0; i < MainDirs.Length; i++)
            {
                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary = true;
                    zip.AddDirectory(MainDirs[i]);
                    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
                    zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
                    zip.Save(string.Format("test{0}.zip", i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your assembly building using the client profile target framework? If so, try changing it to the full profile .net 4.5 (you can change this in project properties)

Comment: Not an answer to your problem but: change c:\\users\\public\reports to c:\\users\\public\\reports or use @"c:\users\public\reports"; also your save location is not correct... perhaps change it to string.Format("c:\\users\\public\\test{0}.zip", i);

Comment: You have to import third party `Ionic.dll`

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid - No you don't - this is part of System.Io.Compression (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: problem is not from where I am taking the files and where I am saving them problem is its not detecting ZipFile

Comment: @Jay no, he's actually correct. The properties that the op is showing is from the Ionic ZipFile: http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid -  I think Jay is right I don't need to import anything other than default compression

Comment: The .NET ZipFile and Ionic ZipFile are **not** interchangable. You cannot set those properties on a .NET ZipFile. Where did you find the example that you are showing?

Comment: @ManojSingh But why is there the line ``zip.CommpressionLevel = `` **``Ionic``** ``.CompressionLevel.BestCompression``?

Comment: @ Binkan -- I don't have any idea of C#. I have just taken it from somewhere. I just want to zip some file using C#, but the condition is I don't want to use any third party library. If you have code then please share. I will just use that

Comment: Can you provide information about the Ionic library. Creating and extracting Zips in dotnet is used as in here  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381661/Creating-Zip-Files-Easily-in-NET

Comment: @ManojSingh This site is not a "please send code to me" site. It is a question and answer site. There is an example in the link that Binkan provided. Did you read his answer?

Comment: **Exactly** what syntax error messages are you seeing in Visual Studio.  Based on the colors, your screen shot seems to show that the IDE knows what `ZipFile` is and that it is a class.  So your assumption that "but its showing that ZipFile class does't exist" would be incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

It is because you are trying to instanciate a static class.

```
using System.IO.Compression;
...

string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

After fixing this it seems to work for me with your code.

**From the documentation :**

> Provides static methods for creating, extracting, and opening zip
>   archives.

More information here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

---

**Solution 2 :**

It's because you've mixed the Ionic library code and and the .Net library reference. If you want to stick with it, you should download the library and add it as reference instead of the .Net libraries.

The library and its documentation can be found here : http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html
or
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Here is a quick example took from the documentation (found within the library zip downloaded on the links above) :

```
string ZipFileToCreate = @"C:\Temp\Test.zip";
string DirectoryToZip = @"C:\Temp\FolderToZip\";
try
{
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.StatusMessageTextWriter = System.Console.Out;
    zip.AddDirectory(DirectoryToZip); // recurses subdirectories
    zip.Save(ZipFileToCreate);
  }
}
catch (System.Exception ex1)
{
  System.Console.Error.WriteLine("exception: " + ex1);
}
```

Comment: Also note that it's probably because he is trying to use an Ionic ZipFile as a .NET ZipFile. The whole example is wrong.

Comment: Fixed the question, thanks. It would still be fine to use that, don't you think ?

Comment: perhaps also an example with Ionic so OP gets the point :)

Comment: @Schuere Is that allright ? :)

Comment: @Andy --  can you please post a complete program to zip a folder containing sub folders and files

Comment: yeah, hopefully for him :)

Comment: @ManojSingh You should have everything here.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll** as a reference.
Info was taken from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Edit**: As the line `zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;` shows, you're confusing the build-in `ZipFile` class etc. (System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll) and the third party library DotNetZip (Ionic.dll)

Comment: yes its already taken

Comment: I have added the screen shot which is showing the reference, still its not working